# Eclipse not loading dependent module in a multi module maven project

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

Environment{git, maven, spring3, tomcat7, STS3.2/Eclipse4.2}

The maven project has the below structure

```
Base
--CoreApi
--CoreImpl
--ModuleBase
----ModuleApi
----ModuleImpl
----ModuleWeb
```

ModuleWeb has a compile time dependancy on CoreApi (jar), ModuleApi (jar) and ModuleImpl (jar).

When I publish the ModuleWeb to the tomcat (using STS) and starting the tomcat, I see the **ModuleImpl is not copied over to the WEB-INF/lib** folder and which eventually results in ClassNotFound like exceptions. Yet the ModuleApi and CoreApi are copied to the lib. And that's the issue !

To mention, I can of course do a `maven clean install` from the terminal without any issues and it successfully generates jars and wars.

In STS > ModuleWeb's project propeties > Deployment Assembly[image]

and the Build path order and export looks like:
[image]

Ofcourse, if I manually copy the ModuleImpl to the WEB-INF/lib, everything works but, that's not how it should be. So, any clue?

That being said, everything was working alright until I had to do some git related changes in the .gitignore to add .settings and .classpath and further do a `git rm -r --cached` and `git add .` Also a series of Project clean, commits and maven installs from terminal. I think something kind of messed up.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ongoing problem with the `m2e-wtp` plugin in Eclipse:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398138

I have not figured out the specific conditions on when it comes up, nor do I have a specific workaround.  I recommend changing the dependency structure, if you can.  Make `ModuleApi` dependent on `ModuleImpl`, for example (even if they're not), or `CoreApi` dependent on `ModuleImpl`.

Comment: ModuleWeb already depends on ModuleImpl as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ah, I was looking at your diagram as a dependency tree.  Anyway, it was just an example.  Try adding `ModuleImpl` as a dependency to `ModuleApi` or `CoreApi`.

Comment: Tried. Didn't improve the situation. The Marker has an error now

A cycle was detected in the build path of project 'hawk-health-hck-api'. The cycle consists of projects {hawk-health-hck-api, hawk-health-hck-impl, hawk-health-hck-web}